# In '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 0:00' this format ,what is this extra '0:00' given in the time unit of 'nc' file?

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I have 5 years of daily data, whose 'time' variable is in the standard calendar, and time is in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). How do I change this to IST(Indian Standard Time) and YYYY-MM-dd format in MATLAB? What is this extra '0:00' given in the time unit of the 'NetCDF' file?
Can anyone help me?
**More details about the variable**: units = 'seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 0:00'; long_name = 'verification time generated by wgrib2 function verftime'; calendar =  standard; Example of datneum is '1514768400.00000'.

Comment: Hard to tell what that extra "0:00" is. Maybe time shift with respect to UTC/GMT? So "0:00" would mean UTC. But without additional information we can only guess

Comment: If the time is in datetime, you can change the timezone via d.TimeZone = 'Asia/Dehli' (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/specify-time-zones.html). If you could give a snippet of example code, that would be helpful. Also please write a more general questions like "How to change timezones of datetimes in Matlab?"

Comment: Hi Ammu! Luis' guess that it's an offset from UTC sounds right to me, because that's what usually goes in that position in a timestamp, though it's usually formatted somewhat differently. The place to look for the answer to this is in the documentation for the particular source of the NetCDF file in question. (NetCDF itself does not specify timestamps that precisely; it's up to the producer of the particular NetCDF file.) Where did you get this NetCDF file? I'm guessing it's meteorological data since the term "grib" is in there?